# Concatenate row values using python

Tags: python, csv, join, row, concatenation

I am new to pyhton and am stuck on this topic from 2 days,tried looking for a basic answer but couldn't,so finally I decided to come up with my question.

I want to concatenate the values of only first two rows of my csv file(if possible with help of inbuilt modules).
Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thnx in advance

### Below is my sample csv file without headers:

```
1,Suraj,Bangalore

2,Ahuja,Karnataka

3,Rishabh,Bangalore
```

### Desired Output:

```
1 2,Suraj Ahuja,Bangalore Karnataka

3,Rishabh,Bangalore
```

Comment: Did you try *writing something*? Where precisely are you stuck?

Comment: Provided you already know how to [read](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [write](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.writer) csv data, you can combine python [lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) and the [zip() function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for your first 2 lines like below:

```
with open('f.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    res = ""
    for i, j in zip(lines[0].strip().split(','), lines[1].strip().split(',')):
        res += "{} {},".format(i, j)
    print(res.rstrip(','))
    for line in lines[2:]:
        print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2,Suraj Ahuja,Bangalore Karnataka
3,Rishabh,Bangalore
```

Comment: Thnx for the . Really Appreciate it . It Worked

Comment: @SurajAhuja You're welcome to SOF. Please, check this link to see how to accept an answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Just create a `csv.reader` object (and a `csv.writer` object). Then use `next()` on the first 2 rows and zip them together (using list comprehension) to match the items.

Then process the rest of the file normally.

```
import csv

with open("file.csv") as fr, open("output.csv","w",newline='') as fw:
    cr=csv.reader(fr)
    cw=csv.writer(fw)
    title_row = [" ".join(z) for z in zip(next(cr),next(cr))]
    cw.writerow(title_row)
    # dump the rest as-is
    cw.writerows(rows)
```

(you'll get an exception if the file has only 1 row of course)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file2', 'r') as f, open('file2_new', 'w') as f2:
    lines = [a.split(',') for a in f.read().splitlines() if a.strip()]
    newl2 = [[' '.join(x) for x in zip(lines[0], lines[1])]] + lines[2:]
    for a in newl2:
        f2.write(', '.join(a)+'\n')
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always consider adding an explanation to it.